# Notepad++ how to ignore a word in lines on notepad++ using "find in files"

Tags: notepad++, search, exclude, ignore

Helly everyone,

I am struggling to find out how to exclude a word in a line of text in notepad++

I am using the "find in files" option to search through many large log files.

My search string is as follows:

```
"Searching for user with username '.*' and domain name"
```

(This will show all usernames where '.*' is the username part. So the result is all names are shown which is great.

However there is a certain username that I want ignored in the output for example `UsernameX1` I do not want to be shown in the output

so output"
I want lines like these to be ignored with word "`usernameX1`" and only show other usernames whilst ignoring usernamex1

So in the output I want this line below to be ignored

```
"Searching for user with username 'usernameX1' and domain name "
```

and only lines like these to show:

```
"Searching for user with username 'usernameA1' and domain name "
"Searching for user with username 'Chrisv' and domain name "
"Searching for user with username 'brianz' and domain name "
```

etc.

Is there a tool, method or plugin I can use that helps me sort this out?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1614038/edit) and add sample text and expected result. Do you want to match `username` or not? It's not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have amended my question. I hope this clarifies it better. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- Find what: `Searching for user with username '(?!usernameX1).+?' and domain name`
- **CHECK** *Bookmark line*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
usernameX1      # usernameX1
)               # end lookahead
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: @ichiban: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)